# Regex.replace will not replace multiline text rows with beginning chars to html block

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Ich have a problem with the regex replacing function in c# explicit in a multiline text. In this text i have different rows sometimes with special chars (eg: & and &&) in the beginning that rows have to convert in e.g. html. It is similar as a markdown conversion...

An example text following:

```
This is a normal demo text.
&Here an other demo text.
And one more demo text.
&&Here will continue this text.
Bla bla blaaa...
```

The text should be after replacing as following text with beginning and end html tag:

```
This is a normal demo text.
<b>Here an other demo text.</b>
And one more demo text.
<em>Here will continue this text...</em>
Bla bla blaaa...
```

For replacing & and && I have created following c# code:

```
private string StartConvert(str text) 
{
text = Regex.Replace(text, "^[&]{1}((?![&]).+)$", "<b>$1</b>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
text = Regex.Replace(text, "^[&]{2}((?![&]).+)$", "<em>$1</em>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
}
```

After running I will get the wrong followings:

```
This is a normal demo text.
</b>ere an other demo text.
And one more demo text.
</em>ere will continue this text...
Bla bla blaaa...
```

Why this does not work correctly and why I get only the closed tags in front of rows. If it is a single Line it works correctly but not in multiline.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How you assign the input?

Comment: I have also tested this ,Regex works fine in Regex maker but when it comes to C# it skips H

Comment: Your code works for me http://ideone.com/XhQzoR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your file is Windows EOF encoded: `\r\n`.

The expression: `"^[&]{1}((?![&]).+)$"` will match `&Here an other demo text.\r\n`.

The back reference `((?![&]).+)` will be `Here an other demo text.\r`.

Having this replacing string: `<b>Here an other demo text.\r</b>`

```
<b>Here an other demo text.\r
^___________________________|
```

CR `\r` returns the cursor to the beginning of the line.

```
</b>ere an other demo text.\r
|__^
```

Rewriting `<b>H` with `</b>`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution but i can tell you that the problem is not in Regex ,The problem is in Printing the **text** .I saw that the Result string is totally fine 
so i did something like this to check it

```
        string[] strings = text.Split(' ');

        foreach (var s in xa)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        }
```

You can check the string while Debug ,it is Ok?